# Probability without replacement (black&red balls)

Tags: probability

An urn contains ten balls, of which five are red and five are black. Five different balls
are to be randomly drawn from the urn without replacement. What is the probability
that at most three balls drawn are red?

I am trying to solve this by doing $1 - P(4) - P (5)$.

$P(5)$ is pretty simple but for $P(4)$ I can find it by writing out all the possibilities but that takes too long. How can I calculate $P(4)$ without having to do this?

Trying to find a way to represent all possible pattern of $P(4)$ because it could be either:

$$\frac{5 \times 5 \times 4 \times  3 \times 2}{10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times6}$$ where the first 5 represents a black ball, also part of $P(4)$ is:

$$\frac{5\times6\times4\times3\times2}{10\times9\times8\times7\times6}$$ where the 6 in the numerator represents a black ball being drawn.

But I don't understand how to represent them since the numerator in both the examples I gave are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of one black ball and four red balls, in that order, is 
$\frac{5}{10} \cdot \frac{5}{9} \cdot \frac{4}{8} \cdot \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{2}{6}$. No matter what order you pick them, you find that the probability stays the same.

Then you account for order. There are $\frac{5!}{1!4!} = 5$ ways to order one black and four red. Your probability is the above product multiplied by $5$. The result is $\frac{25}{252}$.

Comment: The probability of getting one black ball is 5/10 not 1/10 right?

Comment: @mch sorry, yes. I've corrected it

Comment: Can you explain to me how you can just multiply it by 5? Because its 5/10 when it is on the first try, but when you want it on the last try its gonna be 5/6. Do you really get the same probability whatever way you arrange all of them and whatever on which try you get the black ball?

Comment: @mch Yes, the numerator and denominator always end up the same numbers. You can try it, you'll just get a reordering of those numbers

Comment: Thank you, I had made a mistake by putting a 6 in the numerator in one of the calculations of P(4). Appreciate the help.